# In sql how to find max from the columns

Tags: sql

Suppose in a table I have 5 columns (a,b,c,d,e) each an integer value and this table has 100 of rows how can we find the maximum from the sum of each column and the column name by sql?That is max(sum(a),sum(b),sum(c),sum(d),sum(e)) and columnname

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Please share your work, what have you tried to solve the problem?. Read "https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask"

Comment: Gordon's answer is as always spot on!

Answer (score 1):

In many databases, you can use `greatest()`:

```
select greatest(sum(a), sum(b), sum(c), sum(d), sum(e))
from t;
```

In databases that don't have this function, you can use `case` or unpivot and reaggregate:

```
select sum(val)
from ((select a as val, 'a' as which from t) union all
      (select b as val, 'b' as which from t) union all
      (select c as val, 'c' as which from t) union all
      (select d as val, 'd' as which from t) union all
      (select e as val, 'e' as which from t)
     ) abcde
group by which
order by sum(val) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

This is ANSI syntax.  Some databases use `TOP` or `LIMIT` instead of `FETCH FIRST`.